# RecyclerView displaying only the first element in the Habits array

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner Android Dev and I can't make the card layout display all habits. I tried swapping walk and water and I got only walk.

Am I missing something or maybe something is incorrect?
HabitsAdapter class

```
    class HabitAdapter(private val habits: List<Habit>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HabitAdapter.HabitViewHolder>() {

    class HabitViewHolder(val card: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(card) {
        fun bind(habit: Habit) {
            card.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view_title).text = habit.title
            card.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view_description).text =
                habit.description
            card.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view_icon)
                .setImageResource(habit.image)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HabitViewHolder {
        return HabitViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HabitViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(habits[position])

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = habits.size
}
```

Habits class

```
    data class Habit(val title: String, val description: String, val image: Int)

fun getSampleHabits(): List<Habit> {
    return listOf(
        Habit(
            "Drink Water",
            "A refreshing glass of water gets you ready for a long day ahead",
            R.drawable.water
        ),
        Habit(
            "Go for a walk",
            "A nice walk helps clear your mind for a long day ahead",
            R.drawable.walk
        )
    )
}
```

MainActivity class

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var itemBinding: SingleItemBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mainBinding.root)

        mainBinding.recyclerViewList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mainBinding.recyclerViewList.adapter = HabitAdapter(getSampleHabits())

    }
}
```

MainActivity XML

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/single_item"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"/>
```

XML layout file for a single card which holds the contents of the habit (i.e. title, description and icon)

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_icon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                tools:src="@drawable/water" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view_icon"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                tools:text="Drink Water" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Drink Water"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view_icon"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_view_title"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Include XML code as well.

Comment: Added the xml in the post. I followed your advice but to no avail.

Comment: The parent `ViewGroup` for each item is a `ScrollView`. That's definitely not what you want. Try removing that and making the `CardView` the parent instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your single_item.xml should look like . Since you had kept height of ScrollView as match parent it was occupying the whole view and there was no place to  recycle hence making it wrap content solves the issue .

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_icon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view_icon"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                tools:text="Drink Water" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Drink Water"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view_icon"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_view_title"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```
````

Comment: This is the reason why only one of your item was getting visible . There was no problem of my adapter in your previous question that you have unticked as answer . Also using ScrollView as parent is not recommendable , use Constraint / Linear / Relative Layout

Answer (score 1):

Check single_item layout, its height might be match_parent and that might cause the problem.